# How can I export a table only containing cells with >N observations?

Tags: stata

I want to export several tables from Stata to Excel but I am only interested in tables where each cell has more than `5` observations. Is there any way I can set a condition in order to do just that?

With the *community-contributed command* `tabout`I tried to do something along the following lines:

```
tabout var1 if n(cell) > 5
```

For cells with less than `5` observations, I would also like the exported table to show another value (such as `.` or `*`) instead of `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export such a table with the *community-contributed* command `esttab`:

```
sysuse auto, clear

bysort foreign rep78 : generate freq = _N
quietly tabulate foreign rep78 if freq >= 5, matcell(A)

forvalues i = 1 / 2 {
    forvalues j = 1 / 4 {
        if A[`i', `j'] == 0 matrix A[`i', `j'] = .
    }
}

esttab matrix(A)

----------------------------------------------------------------
                        A                                       
                       c1           c2           c3           c4
----------------------------------------------------------------
r1                      8           27            9            .
r2                      .            .            9            9
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

A general approach is two passes, one to calculate cell frequency in a new variable and the other to tabulate conditional on that variable.

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. tab foreign rep78

           |                   Repair Record 1978
  Car type |         1          2          3          4          5 |     Total
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
  Domestic |         2          8         27          9          2 |        48 
   Foreign |         0          0          3          9          9 |        21 
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         2          8         30         18         11 |        69 

. table foreign rep78

----------------------------------------
          |      Repair Record 1978     
 Car type |    1     2     3     4     5
----------+-----------------------------
 Domestic |    2     8    27     9     2
  Foreign |                3     9     9
----------------------------------------

. bysort foreign rep78 : generate freq = _N

. table foreign rep78 if freq >= 5

----------------------------------
          |   Repair Record 1978  
 Car type |    2     3     4     5
----------+-----------------------
 Domestic |    8    27     9      
  Foreign |                9     9
----------------------------------
```

More general code would support `if` and `in` conditions.

Comment: Thank you!                                                                                                            Works perfectly, however when I use the condition (freq >= 5 in your example) STATA returns 0 in the cell with less than 5 observations. Is it possible to to change the 0 with another value such as . or *?                                                                     Kind regards.

Comment: I can't see your data or your code. If you're alluding to some result from `tabout` (SSC), sorry, but  I can't help there, as I don't use it.  For STATA read Stata, always.